# Load variable from script

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-import, optionmenu

I know it is a common question, but I can't find a solution which is similar with mine.
I have two program files - a GUI-File (tkinter) and the Main-File, which is feeding the Gui with input.

It works fine until I want to put an OptionMenu into the GUI-File, which is getting the List from the Main-File.

I know that's normally works with:

`from GUI-File import variable_from_Main-File`

BUT! When I do this the whole file is loaded before the GUI is finished, so variables are just undefined on some points than.

Here is the code for better understanding:

1st the Main-File

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import DLE_Gui as gui

xmlOriginUp = open('%s' %gui.load.Filename, 'r')
xmlOrigin = ET.parse(xmlOriginUp)

elemList    = []
tags        = []

for elem in xmlOrigin.iter():
    elemList.append(elem)

for ta in range(len(elemList)):
    tags.append(elemList[ta].tag)
```

And the GUI-File:

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, Button, LabelFrame, Label, Entry, messagebox, Text, OptionMenu, StringVar
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from DLE_v200609 import tags

def fin():
    gui.destroy()

def load():        
    load.Filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("XML", "*.xml"),("All files", "*.*")))
    print(load.Filename)    
    Label(text=load.Filename, bg="white", borderwidth=2, relief="sunken").grid(row=1, column=1)


gui = tkinter.Tk()
gui.title('Dante Label XML-Export')


Label(text='Öffnen:').grid(row=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
Label(bg="white", borderwidth=2, relief="sunken").grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=178)
Button(text='dursuchen...', command=load).grid(row=1, column=2, ipadx=5)

Label(text='Label:').grid(row=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
var = StringVar(gui)
var.set('---')
optMen = OptionMenu(gui, var, tags)
optMen.grid(row=2, column=1)

Button(text='Schließen', command=fin).grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

gui.mainloop()
```

So I want the list 'tags[]' as variable list of the Option Menu in the GUI.
The answer of the program is:

```
xmlOriginUp = open('%s' %gui.load.Filename, 'r')

AttributeError: module 'DLE_Gui' has no attribute 'load'
```

Has anybody an idea how can I solve it, please?

Comment: How are these two scripts being executed?

Comment: all your idea seems wrong. You can't get `gui.load.filename` without running `gui.load()` first. You should create empty `OptionMenu` at start and later inside `load()` get values from file and add to `OptionsMenu`.

Comment: BTW: if you use `tkinter.Tk()` (and similar) then you need only `import tkinter`, and you don't need `from tkinter import Tk`

Comment: or you should run `load()` at start without using `button` and create `tags` before you display `GUI` (`tkinter.Tk` and rest)

Comment: BTW: maybe you should put all code in one file - it will be simpler. And then you can organize lines in correct order, first read file, next create tag, next display GUI with `OptionMenu`.

Comment: `gui` module alias name is overrided by `gui = tkinter.Tk()`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Its really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your idea with two files seems wrong.

You could put all code in one file to make it simpler.

---

To create tags you have to read file but to get filename you have to display GUI with button which runs `load()` - but at the same time you try to get filename without displaying GUI and without running `load()`.

You should create `GUI` with empty `OptionMenu` as start

```
 option_menu = tk.OptionMenu(gui, var, '---')
```

to display it before you load data from file for this `OptionMenu`

And when you press `Button` then `load()` should read file and add items to `OptionMenu`

```
for item in xmlOrigin.iter():
    option_menu['menu'].add_command(label=item.tag)
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# --- functions ---

def load():
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("XML", "*.xml"),("All files", "*.*")))
    print(filename)

    label_filename['text'] = filename

    xmlOriginUp = open(filename)
    xmlOrigin = ET.parse(xmlOriginUp)

    for item in xmlOrigin.iter():
        option_menu['menu'].add_command(label=item.tag)

# --- main ---

gui = tk.Tk()
gui.title('Dante Label XML-Export')

l = tk.Label(text='Öffnen:')
l.grid(row=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

label_filename = tk.Label(bg="white", borderwidth=2, relief="sunken")
label_filename.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=178)

b = tk.Button(text='dursuchen...', command=load)
b.grid(row=1, column=2, ipadx=5)

l = tk.Label(text='Label:')
l.grid(row=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

option_menu_var = tk.StringVar(gui)
option_menu_var.set('---')

option_menu = tk.OptionMenu(gui, option_menu_var, '---') # create empty OptionMenu
option_menu.grid(row=2, column=1)

b = tk.Button(text='Schließen', command=gui.destroy)
b.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh thank you really much for your fast answer! As you notice correctly I am a beginner and like to program small helpful tools. The concept of a GUI is quite new for me. So thanks for tiding up my brain ;)